# Update Data in SSIS row by row

Tags: ssis, oledbcommand

1) I am working on one of the package where I need to get process the data row by row. For more detail information first see attached screen shot in "SourcePicture1" which is the source information.
[image]
2) Then based on formula using Derived column I have created new columns using two source columns (Name and value) in SSIS package that you can see attached screen shot "SourcePicture2"
[image]
3) Now, I would like to have result as shown in attached file "Result"

[image]

Comment: I have tried to write single and individual update statement for each name type but its gave me NULL value for "RFlg" column. However, I would like to have "Y" in "RFlg" column and N for other two respective columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/aggregate-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) component.   Group on the columns that are the same for each row, and use MAX for the three new columns.